# Twilio - No way to catch if end user ended the call

Tags: javascript, twilio

We are currently using Twilio to make in browser calls - all works fine but it seems there is no way to identify when the end user has ended the call. I want to be able to automatically recognise that the user hung up and end the call in the browser. Is there some callback or status that i'm missing?

Here is the code:

```
class window.BrowserCall
  initTwilioDeviceBindings = ->
    twilio_token = $('#twilioToken').data('token')

    # Create the Client with a Capability Token
    Twilio.Device.setup(twilio_token, {debug: true});
    #/* Let us know when the client is ready. */
    Twilio.Device.ready ->
      $("#log").text("Ready")

    #/* Report any errors on the screen */
    Twilio.Device.error (error) ->
      $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message)

    #/* Log a message when a call connects. */
   Twilio.Device.connect (conn) ->
      $("#log").text("Successfully established call")
      $('#call').addClass("hidden")
      $('#hangup').removeClass("hidden")

    #/* Log a message when a call disconnects. */
    Twilio.Device.disconnect (conn) ->
      $("#log").text("Call ended")
      $('#call').removeClass("hidden")
      $('#hangup').addClass("hidden")

  initFormBindings = ->
    $('#call').bind "click", (event) ->
      params = {"phone_number": 
        $('#phone_number').val(),"task_id":$('#task_id').val()
      }
      connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params)
      connection.disconnect (conn) ->
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll()
        console.log 'the call has ended'
        return

    $('#hangup').bind "click", (event) ->
      Twilio.Device.disconnectAll()

  constructor: ->
    initTwilioDeviceBindings()
    initFormBindings()
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `disconnect` handler never gets called? Have you tried defining a [`disconnect` handler on the connection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#disconnect) itself?

Comment: disconnect only gets called if call is ended from this side not from end user. i've tried adding disconnect  to the connection but that doesn't seem to work either - i've added that bit to the question, perhaps it's wrong? @philnash

Comment: This is weird. I just ran the Twilio Client example app, called myself and then hung up from the phone and my disconnect handler was called. Could it be something about the CoffeeScript transpilation and the way you redefined the `Twilio.Device` to `twilio_device`?

Comment: interesting, could you share your code with me and how you define it? would really appreciate it @philnash

Comment: This is the view: https://gist.github.com/philnash/2d6f6938403a182a68075006299c753e. The server just creates a token and a client name.

Comment: I changed the twilio_client bit with no effect and I tried moving the code to the view itself (and changed it to JavaScript rather than coffeescript) but the disconnect handler is still not called when end user hangs up @philnash

Comment: Is there a webhook or something that I’m missing? Does the `initFormBindings` function look correct?

Comment: There are no webhooks. Your code looks right to me, so I don't know why it's not working I'm afraid. I'm a bit stumped with this.

Comment: @philnash i've tried copying the code in the gist verbatim too but doesn't work. when you say that your disconnect handler was called did the log text get updated to "Call ended"

Comment: That's so weird. The log text was updated to "Call ended" for me. Can I ask what browser you're using for this?

Comment: the latest version of chrome @philnash

Comment: I really am lost on this I'm afraid. I'm trying to get some attention from the team behind this now.

Comment: @philnash any chance any of you solved this? I'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: I did not, I could never reproduce this myself. All I can recommend is that you use the latest version of Twilio Client.

Comment: @philnash  I am using the latest version of Twilio JS (1.9.7), I met the same problem with Robbo & 6opko. I have defined "var device = new Twilio.Device(token, {options});" & "device.on('disconnect', function (conn) { log('Call ended.');" event, however, Twilio didn't fired into disconnect event when user hung up. (It works fine if hung up in my browser)
I am using latest version of FireFox...